# How to add a field to a specific page in multipage gravity form?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I'm building a family subscription multipage form with Gravity Forms and I'm fetching the children from a third party database. I'd like to loop through the children and display name inputs, grade dropdowns, etc. for each of them.

I can't figure out how to add the fields to a specific page in the form. Adding fields using the gform_pre_render hook adds the fields to the end of the form. I've tried setting the pageNumber, but still no luck.

```
function children_populate($form) {
// Add fields
    $new_field_id = 0;
    foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        if( $field->id > $new_field_id ) {
            $new_field_id = $field->id;
        }
    }
    $new_field_id++;
    $properties['type'] = 'text';
    $properties['pageNumber'] = 1;
    $field = GF_Fields::create( $properties );
    $field->id = $new_field_id;
    $field->label = 'Another New Field';
    $field->pageNumber = 1;
    $form['fields'][] = $field;

  return $form;
}
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', 'children_populate' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_2', 'children_populate' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_2', 'children_populate' );
```

The above, just added the fields at the end of the form. I'd like to have it show up on the second page of my 5 page form.

Comment: Not sure if GF actually does a sorting of the fields by this page number; it might be that it just uses this value in a “control break” fashion to determine that a new page starts, when the value changes from one field to the next. So in that case, you would have to see to it that you get your new field inserted in the right position yourself.

Comment: Might make sense to create new array for that purpose. Loop over the original one, and insert the fields to the new one, one by one. When you reached the position where you want to insert your new field (up to you, how exactly you want to determine that), insert that new field, then continue adding the rest of the original fields to the new array. Overwrite $form['fields'] with that new array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the form object to find the Page field that represents the page you want to add your fields to. Then you can use `array_splice` to add your new fields to this page at the next index *after* that page field. You will still need to set the `$field->pageNumber` property for each child field.

This snippet demonstrates the concept but does not handle actually generating the array of child fields to be inserted on the desired page.

```
$target_index = false;
foreach( $form['fields'] as $index => $field ) {
    // Update "2" to your target page number.
    if( $field->type == 'page' && $field->pageNumber == 2 ) {
        $target_index = $index + 1;
        break;
    }
}

array_splice( $form['fields'], $target_index, 0, $child_fields );
```